# Getting asyncua.sync.ThreadLoopNotRunning: error when the retrying connection is made after disconnection

Tags: python, async-await, opc-ua

I have used asyncua Library to get the data from OPC server. This is the simple example of the code I have used in the application, I am getting these error randomly.
Describe the bug
Calling connect() after disconnect() will raise ThreadLoopNotRunning error.

To Reproduce

```
>>> client = Client('opc.tcp://localhost')
>>> client.connect()
>>> client.disconnect()
>>> client.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/sync.py", line 95, in        wrapper
    result = self.tloop.post(aio_func(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/user/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/sync.py", line 51, in post
    raise ThreadLoopNotRunning(f"could not post {coro}")
    asyncua.sync.ThreadLoopNotRunning: could not post <coroutine object Client.connect at               0x7faf0b51ace0>
```

In library The asynchorous method is used (async/await) but In my application I am used these await/async methods. Is these a possible reason for above error or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The library has a current limitation that you need a new client for each connect.

There is a open issue https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/issues/1364

Comment: Hello @Schroeder , In my application I am creating a new client for every connect but still getting above error, Can you guide what steps need to be take?